# Local Variable in UPDATE() T-SQL Trigger Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I am working on a Trigger to update a change log table for a table with sales facts. When someone tries to make an update on the table, they must write a description and then the update is logged (user, time, table, field, Table_Unique_ID, oldvalue, newvalue)

I am trying to use the UPDATE() Trigger Function for local variable @fieldname. The goal is this way I am only comparing the deleted/inserted values for the columns which are updated, rather than cycling through to check each column. I have been able to use the UPDATE() function when I explicitly state the column name, but not if I set a variable to the column name I want to check.

I really appreciate any advice on how to optimize this process! I still have so much to learn, and this is my first attempt at logging changes.

Below is my Trigger in entirety:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_UpdateLog]

 ON [dbo].[Test_Update_Trigger]
    AFTER  Update
 AS

Declare @description nvarchar(1000)
, @UserName nvarchar(128)
, @oldValue nvarchar(255)
, @newValue nvarchar(255)
, @UniqueID nvarchar(255)
, @fieldname nvarchar(128)
, @oname NVARCHAR(100)
, @OldSQL nvarchar(max)
, @NewSQL nvarchar(max)
, @i int
, @c int
, @numcolumns int
, @numrows int;
DECLARE @updated_table TABLE ( 
idx int Primary Key identity(1,1)
, uniqueID nvarchar(255) NULL )
;


--Require the User to submit a description for the update
Set @description = (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Fact_Bookings_Audit_Description])
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Fact_Bookings_Audit_Description]

IF @description is null 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'You must provide a description. Use the following text:

    TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Fact_Bookings_Audit_Description]
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Fact_Bookings_Audit_Description]
    SELECT "Your Text Here--use Single Quotes"

    Copy and paste above your query, type your description, and run the update again.
    ';
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END

--Set User and Table name
Set @Username = system_User
SET @oname = (SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) from sys.triggers where object_ID = @@PROCID)


-------------------------------------------------------------
---create tables of updated items to reference for old/new values
INSERT INTO @updated_table
SELECT distinct Table_ID from DELETED

SELECT * INTO dbo.tempDelete FROM DEleted 
SELECT * INTO dbo.tempInsert FROM inserted
--------------------------------------------------
--Set variables for loop through updated items
Set @i  = 1
Set @numrows = (SELECT count(*) from @updated_table)
------------------------------------------------------------
---Set number of columns for loop through each field
Set @numcolumns = (SELECT MAx(ordinal_position) FROM information_schema.columns where table_name = @oname )

---------------------------------------------------------------
--If there was an update
IF @numrows > 0
BEGIN
    --loop through each individual updated row
    WHILE (@i <= (select max(idx) from @updated_table))
    BEGIN
        --reset the column variable
        Set @c = 1
        --loop through each column
        WHILE (@c <= @numcolumns)
        BEGIN
                Set @fieldname =    (SELECT Column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
                                        Where table_name = @oname AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @c)

                    /**This is what I want to use--
                    I would only like to do the comparison on columns which were updated, not cycle through every column**/

                    --IF UPDATE(@fieldname)
                    --BEGIN

                    --set values for old and new values as well as unique ID for log table
                    Set @UniqueID = (SELECT uniqueID from @updated_table u WHERE idx = @i)
                    Set @OldSQL = 'SELECT @oldvalue = ' + @fieldname + ' from dbo.tempdelete d WHERE d.Table_ID = ' + @UniqueID;
                    Set @NewSQL = 'SELECT @newvalue = ' + @fieldname + ' from dbo.tempInsert i WHERE i.Table_ID = ' + @UniqueID;

                    EXEC sp_executesql @oldSQL, N'@oldvalue nvarchar(128) output', @oldValue = @oldValue output
                    EXEC sp_executesql @newSQL, N'@newvalue nvarchar(128) output', @newValue = @newValue output

                    ;
                        --Insert into log table if value is changed
                        IF isnull(@oldvalue,0) <> isnull(@newvalue,0)
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO dbo.Fact_Bookings_ChangeAudit (Change_Date, Change_Time, [User], Table_Name, Field, Table_ID, Oldvalue, Newvalue, [Description])
                            VALUES(cast(datediff(DAY,0,getdate())as datetime),cast(getdate() as datetime),@UserName, @oname, @fieldname, @UniqueID, @oldValue, @newValue, @description);
                        END
                    --END
                --next column
                Set @c = @c + 1
        END
    --next record
    Set @i = @i + 1
    END

END
DROP TABLE dbo.tempDelete
DROP table dbo.tempInsert

GO
```

Comment: I think a lot of things in there are a bad idea. You don't need the `mysql` tag either. I know it's your first question but there's probably too much to comment on.

Comment: In my opinion this question kind of straddles two stackexchange sites, this one and code review. You may want to post there though since you are looking for optimization. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, @shawnt00. I have removed the Mysql tag. Still learning right now. If you have any good articles relating to tracking changes I would appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks @scsimon! I know there is probably a lot I can do to optimize.. It's an iterative process. Do you know why I cannot use a local variable in the UPDATE() function?

Comment: A variable in `update()` doesn't make sense. It's telling you which columns changed and why you're inside the trigger.

Comment: @shawnt00, my understanding is is returns TRUE for UPDATE(column_name) if column_name was updated. So I thought the local variable being set to column name may work.. but that is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I see what you were intending to do there.

Comment: As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), `UPDATE()` takes a _column_ as an argument, not an expression, string, ... . IIRC, `UPDATE()` will return `TRUE` if an assignment is made to a column even if it doesn't result in a change in the column's value, e.g. `update Foo set Bar = Bar where Id = 42`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with i as (
    select
        case when updated(colA)
            then coalesce(cast(ColA as varchar(32)), 'null') end as newColA,
        case when updated(colB)
            then coalesce(cast(ColB as varchar(32)), 'null') end as newColB,
        ...
    from inserted
), d as (
    select
        case when updated(colA)
            then coalesce(cast(ColA as varchar(32)), 'null') end as oldColA,
        case when updated(colB)
            then coalesce(cast(ColB as varchar(32)), 'null') end as oldColB,
        ...
    from deleted
), old as (
    select c.Id, Col, Change
    from i unpivot (Change for Col in (newColA, newColB, ...))
    where Change is not null
), new as (
    select c.Id, Col, Change
    from d unpivot (Change for Col in (oldColA, oldColB, ...))
    where Change is not null
)
-- insert into Log
select ...
from
    old o inner join new n on n.Id = o.Id and n.Col = o.Col
```

Listing out the columns is the right way to do this. I know you were hoping to use a loop over the information schema tables. I just don't think all that dynamic sql is a good idea.

I think the query above may be a starting point for creating the list of rows that you want to log. I have not attempted to test it. It might be slow if you try to do a mass update.

This might be faster on the bulk updates rather than using the join?

```
with ...
, new as (select 'i' as src ...),
, old as (select 'd' as src ...),
, combined as (select * from new union all select * from old)
select
    Id, Col
    min(case when src = 'i' then Change end) as newVal,
    min(case when src = 'd' then Change end) as oldVal,
from combined
group by Id, Col;
```

Comment: Okay this is a great starting point for trying another strategy! I will let you know how it goes. I appreciate the feedback. Just curious, what are the potential downsides you see to the dynamic sql?

Comment: Dynamic SQL has a lot of drawbacks especially with security and triggers can be complicated enough. If you search around I think you'll find some bugs and weird behavior when you do this kind of thing. Off the top of my head I can't name one though. But mostly I think that performance is going to be a big issue if you have all those extra queries firing off right in the middle of a simple update.

Comment: On projects with many tables needing history, I have had good results querying the data dictionary to programatically  _create_ the triggers, or alter as the case may be, to reduce typing.

Comment: @shawnt00 Thank you again for your feedback. I have implemented this strategy and noticed an immediate impact in the ability to handle larger batch updates.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance Do you by chance have any links that I could use to learn more about what you mentioned in your post? I think that is a great idea and would like to research more.

Comment: I believe the slowdown is from the join between the inserted and deleted results. You might look into finding another way to pair those off. I think @ShannonSeverance's point was that you can script out the creation of the triggers for convenience. But that's really only to spare all the information schema lookups.